# Order by in SSRS url

Tags: sql, reporting-services

In my WPF application , the user can choose the order of the fields returned in the report and I have to send it in the URL. Is it possible? How is the syntax to do it?

Thanks.

Comment: You could add a parameter to the report being called and set that parameter via the url. Then sort your data based on the created parameter's value.

Comment: You want to change the order of columns in a tablix based on use input? Is that right?